# Объясните пож. просто чудеса происходят))) Вопрос по js

Tags: javascript

На скриншоте явно видно, что результат 0.3, т.е все работает как нужно. Но, если вырезаю и вставляю это же условие в this.dasplayValue = ..... , то, при уже выдает NaN, хотя условие тоже.
Подскажите пож. в чем ошибка, и как сделать, чтоб калькулятор работал корректно. Обычные числа считал без остатка, а дробные показывал без знаменитой всем ошибки 0. 3000000000000000004

```
calc() {
      this.displayValue = eval(Math.floor(this.displayValue * 100) / 100);
      // console.log(eval(Math.floor(this.displayValue * 100) / 100));
    },
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      item: ['-', 9, 8, 7, '+', 6, 5, 4, '.', 3, 2, 1, 0, '*', '/'],
      displayValue: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    buttonShow(num) {
      this.displayValue += num;
    },
    clear() {
      this.displayValue = '';
    },
    calc() {
      this.displayValue = eval(Math.floor(this.displayValue * 100) / 100);
      // console.log(eval(Math.floor(this.displayValue * 100) / 100));
    },
    back() {
      if (this.displayValue) {
        this.displayValue = this.displayValue.substring(
          0,
          this.displayValue.length - 1
        );
      }
    },
    percent() {
      this.displayValue = this.displayValue / 100;
    },
  },
}).mount('#app');
```

```css
.grid{ 
   max-width: 360px;
   margin: 50px auto;
   padding: 20px;
   display: grid;
   grid-gap: 10px;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
   background-color: #233244;
   user-select: none;

}

.item {
   padding: 15px;
   border: none;
   color: white;
   font-size: 28px;
   background-color: #31455e;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: .3s ease-in;
}

.item:hover{
   transform: scale(1.05);
   background-color: turquoise;
}

.input {
   background-color: #31455e;
   grid-column: 1/-1;
   height: 50px;
   outline: none;
   text-align: right;
   padding-right: 10px;
   font-size: 28px;
   color: white;
}

.equally{
   grid-column: 4/-1;
   grid-row: 5/7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Calculator</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id='app'>
      <div class="grid">
         <input class="input" type="text" readonly v-bind:value="displayValue">
         <button class="item" @click="clear()">C</button>
         <button class="item back" @click="back()">&loarr;</button>
         <button class="item" @click="percent()">%</button>
         <button class="item" v-for="i of item" @click="buttonShow(i)">{{i}}</button>
         <button class="item equally" @click="calc()">=</button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
   <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всему виной некорректная проверка.

Так, сначала вычисляется выражение

```
this.displayValue = eval(this.displayValue);
```

И лишь затем происходит вывод

```
console.log(eval(Math.floor(this.displayValue * 100) / 100));
```

В данном случае `this.displayValue` - уже число, а не строка, поэтому все отрабатывает корректно.

В случае без `console.log`

```
this.displayValue = eval(Math.floor(this.displayValue * 100) / 100);
```

`this.displayValue` - это строка, и результат умножения может варьироваться в зависимости от конкретного значения.

Так как, например, строка `0.1+0.2` - не может привестись к числу, результат умножения - `NaN`.

Для решения, достаточно сначала вычислить выражение и лишь затем округлять

```
Math.floor(eval(this.displayValue) * 100) / 100
```

Пример

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      item: ['-', 9, 8, 7, '+', 6, 5, 4, '.', 3, 2, 1, 0, '*', '/'],
      displayValue: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    buttonShow(num) {
      this.displayValue += num;
    },
    clear() {
      this.displayValue = '';
    },
    calc() {
      this.displayValue = Math.floor(eval(this.displayValue) * 100) / 100;
    },
    back() {
      if (this.displayValue) {
        this.displayValue = this.displayValue.substring(
          0,
          this.displayValue.length - 1
        );
      }
    },
    percent() {
      this.displayValue = this.displayValue / 100;
    },
  },
}).mount('#app');
```

```css
.grid {
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  background-color: #233244;
  user-select: none;
}

.item {
  padding: 15px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
  background-color: #31455e;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s ease-in;
}

.item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  background-color: turquoise;
}

.input {
  background-color: #31455e;
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  height: 50px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: white;
}

.equally {
  grid-column: 4/-1;
  grid-row: 5/7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id='app'>
    <div class="grid">
      <input class="input" type="text" readonly v-bind:value="displayValue">
      <button class="item" @click="clear()">C</button>
      <button class="item back" @click="back()">&loarr;</button>
      <button class="item" @click="percent()">%</button>
      <button class="item" v-for="i of item" @click="buttonShow(i)">{{i}}</button>
      <button class="item equally" @click="calc()">=</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```